# Apache virtual hosts doesn't work

Tags: php, apache

I would want to setup virtual hosts, on my apache.

`sudo a2enmod vhost_alias  -> Module vhost_alias already enabled`

i have this 2 files:

*/var/www/test/index.php* and */var/www/test2/index.php*

And i want to load them respectivly

http://test.local/ and http://www.test.local/

or

http://test2.local/ and http://www.test2.local/

**my conf file**: (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf)

```
UseCanonicalName Off
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.local
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1+
</VirtualHost>
VirtualDocumentRoot /www/hosts/%0/docs
VirtualScriptAlias /www/hosts/%0/cgi-bin
```

I don't undestand what i'm doing wrong, help me please. I am googling for 2 days but nothing. I have readed http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html but it doesn't help me.
Could you tell me how i should config my files?

Comment: have you enabled the line that say include vhosts file in apache config ?

Answer (score 2):

Did you add in your /etc/hosts file this lines ?

```
127.0.0.1 test.local
127.0.0.1 www.test.local
127.0.0.1 test2.local
127.0.0.1 www.test2.local
```

**EDIT**

Try with this config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test
    <Directory  "/var/www/test/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Until this works try just with one domain, then you will configure the aliases for the others one

Then save this file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/test.local.conf

Then

```
sudo a2ensite test.local.conf
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

go to http://test.local

Comment: i added and now http://test.local/


Not Found


The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Comment: Do you restart apache after editing the vhost config?you have to enable vhost configuration with a2ensite myvhostconfig.conf then reload apache.

Comment: but i config /000-default.conf i dont create any new conf file.

Comment: Do you have some error message when you restart apache? Look at apache error log file too. If I where you I would try with a config file without regex for only one domain, until this work. I post you an apache vhost config file in the answer

Comment: Don't forget to put the original config file in your 000-default.conf and reload apache after that, I would let this unchanged and make my vhosts on their separate config file

Comment: i think u don't undestand my question. I can config 1 2 3 and more sites if i use for each new config file+ host config line, its working, but i dont want to.
I want to config at once my config, and if i want a new site, i just create new dir in /var/www/ and go in brower to its name+.local and i am there. test and test2 it was example. i want to create /var/www/{site_name}/ and going http://{site_name}.local/ whithout any reconfiguring my apach files.

Comment: Ok, I wanted to know if in a classic configuration it warked. I don't know this implementation, I never used that, but I found that you have to activate the modue mod_vhost_alias to use VirtualDocumentRoot: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html. Be sure that each config /www/hosts/%0/cgi-bin exists and I don't know why you put this line : VirtualDocumentRoot /www/hosts/%0/docs. Look at the apache error log, it tells you all you want to know about your errors